# During a transition, how do I get the resulting offsets of other elements?

Tags: javascript, css

Say I have two block level elements in the same container. I want to increase the height of the first (closer to top of page) one, and use a transition on that height. How do I get the resulting offsetTop of the second div, **before** the transition ends?

I don't want to know how to do it for this example. I want to know how to do it for a generic case. Many other elements may be going through transitions at the same time, not just the element directly above the one I am interested in.

The only way I can think of doing it is to force the transitions to end, check the position, and then restart all the transitions. ...but means I have to do it as the transitions start. ...and it causes a flicker when the page is repainted with the temporarily finished transitions.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/AyAfEXu/2

Comment: Do you need a pure javascript solution, or is using jQuery an option?

Comment: Using jQuery is an option, so long as I'm still using Css transitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to clone all your elements once you have added the classes that trigger the CSS transitions, then you can get the resulting properties from the cloned elements which will immediately hold the new values.

I suggest the use of a container element:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two">
        <div id="curr">current offsetTop of P:</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And with jQuery you would do:

```
$(function () {
    //Kick off animations
    $('#one').addClass('loaded');

    //Clone container and position it outside of view
    var $cloneContainer = $('#container').clone().css({
        position: 'absolute',
        left: '-99999px'
    }).prependTo('body');

    //Get offset from cloned element
    var newOffset = $cloneContainer.find('#two').offset().top;
    console.log(newOffset);

    //Remove clone
    $cloneContainer.remove();
});
```

Here's a **[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/mcuwy/2/)** of this approach

Comment: ...What? Adding those together doesn't make sense. How does that give me the value that I _will_ get if you're only working with current values?

Comment: hahaha, I see what's happening. This only _appears_ to work because of the numbers we are working with. The initial height of `q` is 150px. But the new height is `300px` **which makes a difference of 150px**.

The q.offsetHeight in your example just happens to be the same value as (p's new offsetTop - p's old offsetTop)

Comment: Any reason for `position: 'absolute',left: '-99999px'` as opposed to `visibility: hidden`? Seems perfect other than that. Same effect, I guess.

Comment: @uber5001 invisible elements still take up space in the page, and we can't use `display: none` because then they wouldn't report any height/offsets. Right now since there's not much going on between cloning and removing the cloned elements, there's no evidence that the elements are even added in the DOM but if there were to be more computations `visibility: hidden` would cause unwanted behavior, see [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/mcuwy/3/) for example